# Error in implementing kmeans clustering

Tags: matlab

There is a grayscale image `A` , I want to apply kmeans clustering with `K=2`, MATLAB gives me an error for the following code, How to resolve?

```
[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(im2double(A),2);
??? Error using ==> minus
Number of array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in ==> kmeans>onlineUpdate at 576
        Del(:,i) = (m(i) ./ (m(i) + sgn)) .* sum((X - C(repmat(i,n,1),:)).^2, 2);

Error in ==> kmeans at 341
        converged = onlineUpdate();
```

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not for MATLAB questions. Perhaps you can try on StackOverflow?

Comment: kmean is expecting a matrix  yet im2double is working on images. I suspect you will need to convert this to a matrix rep.

Answer (score 0):

you need to break the image to 'vector' components in orded to use Matlab kmeans.
See the example here:
http://imageprocessingblog.com/?p=178